# Type error on draw image function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

For some reason i can't get my image to display in canvas.. i get a type error.

My script is very basic.. its this:

```
var logoImg = new Image();
logoImg.src = 'splash.png';
    ctx.drawImage(logoImg.src, 0, 0);
```

What does it mean when it says type error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have the `.src`.

```
ctx.drawImage(logoImg, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Ah that solved it, also for some reason i had to put 1,1 as its location =/ 0,0 didn't make it display... very odd!

Comment: 0, 0 should definitely work. Try adding the next two parameters which are the images width and height: (logoImg, x, y, width, height)